# Problem with Unorderd list layout and paragraph after it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an unordered list to show both pros and cons about a product and some spec's underneath.

How can I make both columns with the same size and how do I avoid the paragraph with "specifications:" from moving from the left side when I add more lines in the ul?
[image: Screenshot here]

The Code I'm using:

```html
<p></p>
<div class="pro-con-list" style="display: block; margin: 40px auto; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; color: #444444; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 15px; letter-spacing: -0.5px;">
  <div class="row collapse" style="margin: 0px -30px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1;">
    <div class="col6" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; width: calc(50% - 45px); float: left;">
      <div class="pros-list args-list" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline;">
        <h3 style="margin: 0px 0px 10px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; color: #47a32a; font-size: 24px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;" id="mcetoc_1f10951jb4">Pros</h3>
        <ul class="green-box" style="margin: 0px auto; padding: 30px; border: 2px solid #47a32a; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; border-radius: 5px; max-width: 250px;">
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 5px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; font-weight: 600; color: #47a32a;">
          </li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 5px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; font-weight: 600; color: #47a32a;">
            <b>Txt</b></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 5px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; font-weight: 600; color: #47a32a;">
            <b>sdfs</b></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 5px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; font-weight: 600; color: #47a32a;">
            <b>sdgsdg</b></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 5px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; font-weight: 600; color: #47a32a;">
            <b>sdgsdg</b></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 5px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; font-weight: 600; color: #47a32a;">
            <b>sdgsdg</b></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 5px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; font-weight: 600; color: #47a32a;">
            <b>jajakafk</b></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 5px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; font-weight: 600; color: #47a32a;">
            <b>afaaaf</b></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 5px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; font-weight: 600; color: #47a32a;">
            <b>afafaf</b></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 5px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; font-weight: 600; color: #47a32a;">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col6" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; width: calc(50% - 45px); float: left;">
      <div class="cons-list args-list" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline;">
        <h3 style="margin: 0px 0px 10px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; color: #d9332b; font-size: 24px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;" id="mcetoc_1f10951jb5">Cons</h3>
        <ul class="red-box" style="margin: 0px auto; padding: 30px; border: 2px solid #d9332b; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style-position: initial; list-style-image: initial; border-radius: 5px; max-width: 250px;">
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 5px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; font-weight: 600; color: #d9332b;">
            <b>Txt</b></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style: none; font-weight: 600; color: #d9332b;">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spacing-element"></div>
<p style="display: block;"><strong></strong></p>
<p style="display: block;"><strong></strong></p>
<p style="display: block;"><strong></strong></p>
<p style="display: block;"><strong></strong></p>
<div style="display: block;">
  <p style="display: block;"><strong>Specification:</strong></p>
  <p><strong>Text</strong></p>
</div>
<p></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://amzn.to/3b8VeMx" class="btn hero__btn" aria-label="Learn How">Buy on
            Amazon</a></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"></p>
```

Comment: either with flexbox or css grid. So specifications shoul always be below the list section? Is there a reason not to use CSS?

Comment: Consider using classes instead of repeating the same inline style 10 times.